# Submenu Bootstrap em JQuery para TypeScript

Tags: html, jquery, css, typescript, nav-bar

eu estou começando meus estudos com TypeScript e estou tentando(e precisando) modificar um código que eu achei pronto, que está em Jquery. Porém eu preciso dele todo em TypeScript, mas nao estou conseguindo fazer funcionar ainda. Alguém aí pode me dar uma ajuda ?

O link de onde eu achei o código é [esse](https://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/PJqKzQ).

Lá tem o código em Jquery funcionando e o html e css pra testar.

Para facilitar, aqui está o código em JQuery:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass("show");
  });


  return false;
});
```

**Código que já tentei fazer:** (a função getParents eu tirei dessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981248/2619912).)

```
function getParents(parentSelector) {

    // If no parentSelector defined will bubble up all the way to *document*
    if (parentSelector === undefined) {
        parentSelector = document;
    }

    var parents = [];
    parents.push(parentSelector); // Push that parentSelector you wanted to stop at

    return parents;
}
```

---

```
    var addDropDown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle');

    for (var i = 0; i < addDropDown.length; i++) {
        addDropDown[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {

            if (!this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('show')) {

                var elemento = getParents(this)[0].querySelectorAll('.show');

                for (var z = 0; z < elemento.length; z++) {
                    elemento[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        elemento[z].classList.remove("show");
                    });
                }

            }
            var $subMenu = this.nextElementSibling(".dropdown-menu");
            $subMenu.classList.toggle('show');

            this.parentNode('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').addEventListener('hidden.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                var itensLista = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-submenu .show');

                for (var x = 0; x < itensLista.length; x++) {
                    itensLista[i].classList.remove("show");
                }
            });


            return false;
        });
    }
```

**Erro no console:**

> Uncaught TypeError: this.nextElementSibling is not a function
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.

A linha indicada pelo erro é esta:

```
var $subMenu = this.nextElementSibling(".dropdown-menu");
```

**OBS: NÃO ESTOU USANDO O JQUERY**

Comment: Por que não está conseguindo fazer funcionar? O compilador apresenta algum erro?

Comment: @user140828, ainda não entendo bem de TypeScript, esse é o motivo kk. Eu não estou agora com o código que eu estava tentando, mas depois eu deixo na pergunta... mas não fui muito longe não. Melhor recomeçar do zero.

Comment: @user140828, eu editei a pergunta, colocando o código que eu já tenho feito, e vou deixar qual o erro que está sendo apresentado no compilador

Comment: O último fragmento não ajuda em nada pois em TypeScript dependendo do lugar onde é usado a palavra-chave `this` ela assume valores distintos.Em um constructor, função membro ou propriedade `this` aponta para a atual instancia da classe em que é usado. Em um método estático ou propriedade estática `this` aponta para o constructor da classe em que é usado. Em uma declaração de função `this` aponta para o escopo da própria função em que é usado. Existe this como parâmetro possuindo sua própria lógica. Edite a pergunta coloque a declaração completa do elemento onde o 'this' problemático ocorre.

Comment: Agradeço pelo comentário, mas poderia deixar uma resposta de como ficaria o código, tendo tudo isso em vista? @AugustoVasques

Comment: Como expliquei sem saber qual o contexto em que se encontra esse `this` e sem saber qual o objeto que ele referencia é impossível responder a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Testei, os problemas e suas correcoes:

```
var $subMenu = this.nextElementSibling(".dropdown-menu");
```

por

```
var $subMenu = this.nextElementSibling;
```

---

```
this.parentNode('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').addEventListener
```

por

```
this.parentNode.addEventListener
```

e adicione para evitar que o menu feche na hora errada

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

```js
var addDropDown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle');

    for (var i = 0; i < addDropDown.length; i++) {
        addDropDown[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
            if (!this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('show')) {

                var elemento = getParents(this)[0].querySelectorAll('.show');

                for (var z = 0; z < elemento.length; z++) {
                    elemento[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        elemento[z].classList.remove("show");
                    });
                }

            }
            var $subMenu = this.nextElementSibling;
            $subMenu.classList.toggle('show');
            this.parentNode.addEventListener('hidden.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                var itensLista = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-submenu .show');

                for (var x = 0; x < itensLista.length; x++) {
                    itensLista[i].classList.remove("show");
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    }

function getParents(parentSelector) {

    // If no parentSelector defined will bubble up all the way to *document*
    if (parentSelector === undefined) {
        parentSelector = document;
    }

    var parents = [];
    parents.push(parentSelector); // Push that parentSelector you wanted to stop at
    return parents;
}
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Submenu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another submenu action</a></li>


              <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#">Second subsubmenu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Subsubmenu action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another subsubmenu action</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>



            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Agora que eu vi é uma função. Eu tinha me perdido na endentação da pergunta. A resposta está correta e meus comentários na pergunta são inválidos.

Comment: Hudson, eu não entendo, eu coloquei o código do mesmo jeito que está o seu mas nao funcionou, a única coisa que nao coloquei foram esses links dos scripts. Seu código há dependencia deles?

Comment: O que acontece é que ele simplesmente não funciona, mas também não me mostra um erro. Quando eu clico no submenu para abrir, ele so vai para a `href="#"` e não abre o outro nível.

Comment: o seu codigo tem erros basicos e falta o evente prevent default de acordo com o que vc mostrou, se tem alguma coisa errado no seu codigo deve ser a ordem das referencias do js, veja se o jquery é o primeiro na ordem isso faz toda a diferença.

Comment: Hudson, eu estou pegando um código que ja esta pronto em jQuery para passar para TypeScript e **NÃO** depender do jQuery... eu gostaria que o código funcionasse sem eu precisar usar o jQuery no meu projeto. Porque se eu fosse utilizar o jQuery, eu pegava aquele código que já está pronto e eu deixei na pergunta.

Comment: @SAMU Eu acho que você está confundindo TypeScript com JS puro. O código que diz que tentou fazer não parece TS.

Comment: Bom, eu preciso em TS :/